# Stripe Issue with Subscription Schedule

Tags: express, stripe-payments, webhooks, payment, subscription

##### I have multiple users and added their subscription schedule at the same time,  like 4 days subscription start on daily basis and it charge auto due to save payment details. Instead, I'm only receiving invoice.payment_succeeded and invoice.payment_failed events for only one user and other doesn't see logs in stripe event log section at developer mode. Here is my code please review it and let me know where i got the response event of a all users to update my database

```
    const setupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({
       customer: user.customerId,
        usage: "off_session",
        automatic_payment_methods: {
        allow_redirects: "never",
       enabled: true,
        },
     });
    
    #payment default attach
    const paymentMethods = await stripe.customers.update(customerId, {
     invoice_settings: {
      default_payment_method: paymentMethodId,
     },
     });
    
    #subscription create
      const subscription = await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.create({
      customer: customerId,
        start_date: unixTimestampSeconds,
    
       end_behavior: "release",
        phases: [
        {
        items: [
         {
           price: priceId,
           quantity: quantity,
           },
        ],
         iterations: iteration,
        },
       ],
     });
    
     const subs = await Subscription.create({
       subscriptionId: subscription?.id,
       userId: userId,
       programId: programId,
      status: subscription.status,
       startDate: start_date,
       endDate: end_date,
     });

     # stripe webhook 

     case "subscription_schedule.released":
        const subscriptionScheduleReleased = event.data.object;
    
        let user = User.findOne({
         where: { customerId: subscriptionScheduleReleased.customer },
     });
    const subscriptionSchedule = await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.retrieve(
      subscriptionScheduleReleased.id
     );
     let newsubscription =
       subscriptionSchedule.subscription ||
      subscriptionSchedule.released_subscription;
     const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(newsubscription);
     const datasubscription = await Subscription.findOne({
       where: { subscriptionId: subscriptionScheduleReleased.id },
     });
     datasubscription.status = subscription.status;
     console.log(subscriptionScheduleReleased, "subscription released");
     // Then define and call a function to handle the event subscription_schedule.released
    break;
```

###### I'm working on a project chit fund system in which I use a subscription schedule for start date of a subscription and save card details for future use and charge auto subscription.  I successfully created the subscription schedule for 3-4 users at a time and their subscription started. I see only one user has succedded their subscription in stripe event log but it is succedded in invoice.payment_succedded event hook. i created the subscription schedule so the flow should be like that i get the response of event in my webhook of subscription_schedule.completed but i didn't get it all could you tell me how this work and when i got all usres subscription succedded and when i get response in my event of subscription_schedule. actullay i want response to update my database for status so where i can find all my users subscription succeddded event response.

I have also configured my webhook endpoint to listen for this specific event, but it doesn't seem to be triggered.

## Events:

> subscription_schedule.aborted subscription_schedule.canceled
> subscription_schedule.completed subscription_schedule.created
> subscription_schedule.expiring subscription_schedule.released
> subscription_schedule.updated

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what the actual issue is, but I think there might be some confusion between Subscriptions and Subscription Schedules.

Subscription Schedule -> Subscription -> Invoice -> Payments

You create the Subscription Schedule, which creates a Subscription, which generates Invoices, which generate payments.

Your Subscription Schedule isn't going to trigger many events, aside from:
-When it's created (`.created`)
-When you update its attributes or when a phase ends (`.updated`)
-When it ends (`.released` in your case, I recall `.completed` and `.canceled` occur when it automatically cancels, and `.aborted` occurs when you force-cancel it though I might be wrong)

Based on what you're describing, I think what you're actually looking for are events related to the downstream Subscription not the top-level Schedule.

If your `start_date` is past or present time, then the response to your Subscription Schedule create will include a Subscription object (otherwise you'll have to wait for the `start_date`).
This Subscription would fire events `customer.subscription.<>`:
-When it's created (`.created`)
-When its status changes, or when the period changes (=>inline with new Invoices), or when you change it (`.updated`)
-When it ends (`.deleted`)

Comment: HI, @Lucky2501 i updated my question with a proper details query.